# R: What am I doing wrong in this for-loop with an if-else statement?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

**Sample data:**

```
df <- data.frame(apples = c(1, 5, 3),
                 oranges = c(5, 3, 5))
```

**Problem:**

```
for(i in names(df)){
  
  if(sum(df$i == 5) == 1){
    
    print(paste("There is only 1 occurance of 5 fruit for", i))
    
  } else {
    
    print(paste("There is more than 1 occurance of 5 fruit for", i))
    
  }
}
```

this gives me

```
[1] "There is more than 1 occurance of 5 fruit for apples"
[1] "There is more than 1 occurance of 5 fruit for oranges"
```

however...

```
> sum(df$apples == 5)
[1] 1
> sum(df$oranges == 5)
[1] 2
```

**My expected output:**

```
[1] "There is only 1 occurance of 5 fruit for apples"
[1] "There is more than 1 occurance of 5 fruit for oranges"
```

I suspect it's some sort of syntax issue, or am I missing something more obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `df[[i]]` not `df$i` in your loop, otherwise it is finding variable `i` in the dataframe. `df$i` is NULL. `sum(NULL == 5)` is 0. You always do that `else` bit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of summing the columns separately you could use `colSums` which is generally much faster. The result of a subsequent `ifelse`, which has names, can be piped into `lapply` to loop over the names (where `_` is the placeholder for the piped object). `sprintf` then inserts them at the formal character `%s`. Gives a list as result.

```
ifelse(colSums(df == 5) > 1, 'only', 'more than') |>
  lapply(X=_, sprintf, fmt='There is %s 1 occurance of 5 fruits for')
# $apples
# [1] "There is more than 1 occurance of 5 fruits for"
# 
# $oranges
# [1] "There is only 1 occurance of 5 fruits for"
```

R >= 4.2 needed.